# Can i change the ARM template of an existing data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

i have a github integrated Dev data factory and a Master data factory in azure. Now i want to use the Master Data factory's ARM template on the Dev data factory. Both of them have a set of common data sets, linked services, integration run times and triggers; also there are a few extra pipelines and data sets in the Master.

So if export the Master DF's ARM and use it on the Dev DF, will there be any overwrites/new creation of datasets/pipelines/ Intergration runtimes? Is it possible to do this in this way?

Comment: do you have git integration on your dev data factory ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use git integration.

Then create Pull Request on Master DF. Now Approve and Merge Pull Request.

[image]

This way you will get All Linked Services and Datasets of Master DF into Dev DF.

[image]

For more information follow this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control)